# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'sw') using google-maps api and rapidapi

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps-api-2, rapidapi

I am facing this error while using google-maps api and and another api from rapidapi.

First this is the code that works:

API -> index.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const URL =
  "https://travel-advisor.p.rapidapi.com/restaurants/list-in-boundary";
// code snippet from "https://rapidapi.com/apidojo/api/travel-advisor/"

const options = {
  params: {
    // bl_latitude: sw.lat,
    // bl_longitude: sw.lng,
    // tr_longitude: ne.lng,
    // tr_latitude: ne.lat,
    bl_latitude: "11.847676",
    tr_latitude: "12.838442",
    bl_longitude: "109.095887",
    tr_longitude: "109.149359",
  },
  headers: {
    "x-rapidapi-host": "travel-advisor.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": "key",
  },
};

export const getPlacesData = async () => {
  try {
    const {
      data: { data },
    } = await axios.get(URL, options);

    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

App.js (giving only difference)

```
const [bounds, setBounds] = useState(null);

const [places, setPlaces] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    getPlacesData().then((data) => {
      // console.log(data);
      setPlaces(data);
    });
  }, []);
```

Code that is giving errors:

API -> index.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const URL =
  "https://travel-advisor.p.rapidapi.com/restaurants/list-in-boundary";
// code snippet from "https://rapidapi.com/apidojo/api/travel-advisor/"

export const getPlacesData = async (sw, ne) => {
  try {
    const {
      data: { data },
    } = await axios.get(URL, {
      params: {
        bl_latitude: sw.lat,
        bl_longitude: sw.lng,
        tr_longitude: ne.lng,
        tr_latitude: ne.lat,
        // bl_latitude: "11.847676",
        // tr_latitude: "12.838442",
        // bl_longitude: "109.095887",
        // tr_longitude: "109.149359",
      },
      headers: {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "travel-advisor.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "key",
      },
    });

    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

App.js

```
useEffect(() => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      ({ coords: { latitude, longitude } }) => {
        setCoordinates({ lat: latitude, lng: longitude });
      }
    );
  }, []);
  // comment: 1

  useEffect(() => {
    getPlacesData(bounds.sw, bounds.ne).then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      setPlaces(data);
    });
  }, [coordinates, bounds]);
```

Just after this change it started giving this error

I have tried my level best bust i am unable to find what is wrong with the code. I used git to can see the difference.

Comment: should I share more code ??

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.  What is the response to the request that gives the error?

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem. You'll need to pass an empty object instead of "null"

const [bounds, setBounds] = useState(null);

This is your current code ^

const [bounds, setBounds] = useState({});

This will make your code work ^

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit unclear, and I can help if you provide your question more concisely with less code as possible.

But the one thing I can say here is that you declared the `bounds` variable as `null` having no property, so how can you access the `sw` property of `bounds` because it's not available at all.

Also, you're not using `setBounds` method to set the `bounds` variable. Am I missing something? Try something like this:

`const [bounds, setBounds] = useState({ sw: 0, ne: 0});`

Comment: I am sorry to be not clear. I resolved the error just by putting a [dot] before ? ie optional chaining ?. 
Actually some places api didnt gave adequate info.

Comment: Where did you put your [dot] ?  @Priyam

Comment: Hi! See the problem was a lot of times we expect some data to be received and we write operations/display/formatting for them but what if we didn’t received in the fashion we expected ? For that we use optional chaining ?. operator. 
Answer: here -> getPlacesData(bounds?.sw, bounds?.ne).then((data) => {….. where i receive this data

Answer (score 0):

Add the optional chaining operator to getPlacesData in `App.js`

```
getPlacesData(bounds?.sw, bounds?.ne)
    .then((data) =>{
        setPlaces(data);
    });
```